# Redirect to root not working

Tags: django, django-views

I have an AJAX request that `POST`s to the url for the following view from `views.py`.

The view executes and prints "redirect", but does not actually redirect the user away from the current view. Why?

```
def confirm_user(request):
    response_json = {"status": "fail"}
    if request.POST:
        join_id = request.POST.get('join_id', "")
        try: 
            u = UserProfile.objects.filter(join_id=join_id)[0].user
            email = u.username
            confirmed = u.userprofile.confirmed
            response_json = {
                "status": "success", 
                "confirmed": confirmed, 
                "email": email }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_json), 
                   mimetype="application/json") 
        except:  
            print "redirect"
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Is it an ajax request ?

Comment: An ajax request posts to the url that loads this view

Comment: (And just to confirm, is `redirect` `django.shortcuts.redirect`?)

Comment: At the top of `views.py` I have `from django.shortcuts import render, redirect`

Comment: @karthikr: I don't think `return HttpResponseRedirect('/')` will make any difference, will it? The JavaScript code that makes the AJAX request needs to be changed if @dielawn1 wants the browser to load a new page when a redirect response is returned.

Comment: @karthikr: I don't understand what you mean there.

Comment: Changing `redirect` to `HttpResponseRedirect` gives the same result

Comment: @karthikr: [as per the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), `redirect` already "Returns an `HttpResponseRedirect`".

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I agree. i was wrong. @dielawn1 out of curiosity, does `HttpResponse` work ?

Comment: @karthikr for some reason you have completely failed to understand what is going on. No kind of redirect will work from the backend if this is an Ajax request, because the request is being handled by the XHR, not by the main browser. The Ajax handler itself will have to set the window location.

Comment: Yes, I can parse information from the `HttpResponse` in the `success` function of my `ajax` call

Comment: @karthikr: "Looking at the view code, i think you should be able to achieve what you are looking for with a plain form submit, rather than ajax" - wouldn't that result in raw JSON being rendered (or, quite possibly, downloaded) by the browser? Without seeing the client-side code it's difficult to tell what the OP is aiming for, but I doubt it's that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make an AJAX request (i.e. a JavaScript `XMLHTTPRequest`), your JavaScript code is entirely responsible for handling the response returned by the server.

The browser won't load a new URL if the server returns a redirect response to your AJAX request, or indeed take any action on its own.

Your handler function that deals with the response from the AJAX request could look at the status code of the response, and set `window.location` to the provided URL if the response is a redirect. If you post your AJAX code, we could advise on that.

Comment: So I understand what you are saying, but have a doubt. If I am making that AJAX POST request upon signup and I want to redirect when registration is complete, even as I handle the redirect with javascript, will the person be logged in

Comment: @barrigaj: assuming you track their login with a cookie, yes.